# React Native - Images become blank after app has been used for a while

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-image

I have a React Native app that displays a lot of images, for example it's fairly similar to Instagram in structure, with a timeline of image-heavy posts, multiple tabs containing user listings, current user's profile etc.

My problem is that when running on iOS simulator or device, after scrolling through the timeline for a bit, switching to some other tabs etc, the images start to disappear (they all have a gray background, and that is all that can be seen).

I assume this is some kind of memory management thing, but I'm unsure of how to handle this. I've searched for SO questions and on various other websites for information but can't find anything relevant to this problem. I guess I need to somehow refresh the image component when it becomes visible again?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: would need more detailed info I'm afraid. How are the images loaded? How is the component state managed? could it be S3 access keys are expiring?

Comment: Hey Max! The components are just standard `<Image>` components (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html), with `source={{uri: 'my_absolute_url_here'}}`. I know they're still in the view hierarchy as their backgroundColour style is gray and that is still visible.